# How to add an app to django admin site which do not required model?

Tags: python, django

How to add an app to django admin site which do not required model?

I mean I need to make inteface for my app. But i dont want to create any tables in databas. Actually it going to work with solr items.

Or maybe someone knows any dummy model which acts like a real model.. but is not related with database table?

So then i can overwrite admin templates.

Comment: You can add custom views and templates to Django admin without using models. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/faq/admin/ Second section from the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can define a model for your app and set the managed Meta option to False so that I won't create a db for you?

From documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed